# Email a url to a private page (with django?)

Tags: django, http, email, url, https

Suppose you have private data on the site www.example.com, entered by user A.

User A wants to give his friend, B, access to the data by entering his e-mail address and clicking "share".
Can we give user B secure access to the page via a single-click URL sent by email?
(assuming that we can send e-mails securely)

If we send a email with a link www.example.com/key=some_unique_secret_key, then it will
be recorded in the browser's history when B click's it - which is bad.

If we send a email with a link www.example.com/key=some_public_unique_key along with a PIN in the body of the email, we create a overhead for user B. He has to look up some PIN and enter it to access the resource.

What if we send a https link, https://www.example.com/key=some_unique_secret_key, create a session when user B clicks on the url, and redirect him to a url without the key. Can this be done without creating a history entry with the secret key?

Is there no way to do this securely without making it cumbersome for user B to access the page?

Comment: Why is the secret key being recorded in user B's browser history a bad thing?  Are you worried about people other than B snooping around B's history, or is there another concern?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the browser's behavior. A user could simply bookmark the link. Therefore, the least intrusive approach is to give the unique key a time limit. After the limit, the key is invalid and the link can simply redirect to a page with an appropriate notice.

You an also chose to notify the creator of the link (User A) that their expired link is still being accessed and they can regenerate a link and send it to their friend.

Comment: If the user bookmarks the link he is explicitly asking the browser to save access to the page, which is fine. I'm trying to avoid the browser storing access credentials to the page without the user knowing.

Comment: About the only thing you can do is stop built-in auto complete by adding `autocomplete="off"` to any form field; but people can still use plugins like LastPass to store credentials. In short; don't count on controlling the browser.